# Laurent Series at Infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I thought that finding the Laurent series was something that was straightforward, however, I am having some difficulty of finding the Laurent series of

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z(1-z)}$$

for $z= \infty$.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

Make the change of variable $w= 1/z$ and then find the Laurent series around $w=0$

Answer (score 9):

We can write for $|z|>1$,

$$\frac{1}{z(1-z)}=-\frac1{z^2}\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{-n-2}$$

Comment: I think it is $-\sum _{i=0}^{\infty} z^{-i-2}$

Comment: @david Indeed.  I've edited accordingly.  Thank you for catching that.

Comment: @MarkViola why don't you split $\frac{1}{z(1-z)}$ in terms of partial fractions. In that case, i guess,  $\frac{1}{z}$ is it's own Laurent series and only $-\frac{1}{1-z}$ has to be expanded. I don't understand why are we allowed to pull the factor $-\frac{1}{z^2}$.

Comment: @AlexanderCska Inasmuch as it is more efficient, I chose to proceed as I did.  Why do you ask?

Comment: @MarkViola I am confused by the factor $-\frac{1}{z^2}$. Anyway, If one is to use partial fraction decomposition, would get a factor of $-\frac{1}{z^2}$. I guess it that as long as the form $a_n(z-a)^n$ is preserved all sort of grouping and factors that look like $(z-a)^n$ are OK.

Comment: @AlexanderCska $$\frac{1}{z(1-z)}=\frac1z\,\frac{1}{z(z^{-1}-1)}=\frac1{z^2}\times \frac1{z^{-1}-1}=-\frac1{z^2}\times\frac1{1-z^{-1}}$$What do you not understand?

Comment: @alexandercska Was there a reason for down voting?

Answer (score 0):

Using generalized Laurentseries with two poles
$$\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} x^k-\frac{x^n}{x-1}+\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate a little more, or add a reference?

Comment: it is simple @Darsen it is a Taylor series about the Zero plus laurent coefficient about two poles ,, I have always wondered why laurent series uses a single pole when the function can have several poles and is not reflected in the series for examples $$\frac{e^{-x}}{(1-x) (x+2)^2}$$ it easy calulate the series about two poles

Comment: $$\sum _{j=0}^{j-1} \frac{1}{36} x^j \left(\frac{4 \text{Subfactorial}[j-1]}{(j-1)!}+\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{j-1} \left(2 e^2 \Gamma (j+1) \Gamma (j,2)+3 \Gamma (j) \left(2^{j+1}+e^2 (j-2) \Gamma (j+1,2)\right)\right)}{\Gamma (j) \Gamma (j+1)}\right)-\left(\frac{\frac{1}{9} (-1) e^2 (-1)^{-j} 2^{1-j}-\frac{1}{3} e^2 (-2)^{-j-1} j}{-x-2}-\frac{e^2 (-2)^{-j}}{3 (x+2)^2}\right) x^j-\frac{x^j}{9 e (x-1)}$$