# How to find the Laurent series expansion of $\frac{2}{z^2-4z+8}$ by long division?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I'm trying to find the Laurent series expansion for
$$ \frac{2}{z^2-4z+8} $$
using polynomial long division.

However, I noticed that if I divide leading with the $8$ term, then I will only get positive power terms, namely
$$ \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}z+\frac{1}{32}z^2 + ... $$
Whereas if I divide leading with the $z^2$ term, then I will get only negative power terms, as in
$$ \frac{2}{z^2} + \frac{8}{z^3}+\frac{16}{z^4} + ... $$

*What is going on?*

(I'm doing this to find the residues, i.e. the coefficient of the $\frac{1}{z}$ term.)

Comment: You should look at residues at singularities $z = 2\pm 2i$.

Comment: The original expression was a little more complicated as in $z=u+2$ for another complex variable $u$, and the whole thing was divided by $z^3$ so I was *really* trying to find the $z^2$ term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you wan't to find a function
$$
f(z):= \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n z^n
$$
defined around $0$ such that $f(z)(z^2-4z+8)=2$. If
$$
f(z)=\frac{2}{z^2} + \frac{8}{z^3}+\frac{16}{z^4} + \cdots 
$$
then $f$ is not defined at $0$. However, if
$$
f(z)= \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}z+\frac{1}{32}z^2 + \cdots
$$
then $f$ is defined at $0$ and doing some algebra you can check that $f(z)(z^2-4z+8)=2$. Thus, your first approach is the correct one. Of course this means that the coefficient for $\frac{1}{z}$ is $a_{-1}=0$.

Comment: Another way to see way your first approach works and the second one doesn't is to evaluate at $0$. Your function is well defined at $0$ and equals $\frac{1}{4}$ there. This means that $a_0=\frac{1}{4}$ in the Laurent expansion.

Comment: Apparently the other expansion gives the Laurent series for the annulus centred at 0 outside the singularities. Is this true?

Comment: Yes the second expansion works when $|z|>1$. In this case $\frac{1}{z}$ is inside the unit circle and that's why all your powers are negative. Your first expansion is the Laurent expansion around $0$ and the second one is the expansion at $\infty$. You can read more about it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384910/laurent-series-at-infinity . In particular, Mark's answer shows the standard way to use that $|z|>1$ to get the series expansion.

Answer (score 2):

The first expansion is a correct power series expansion in the disk centered at $0$ with the two bad points at its edge. The second is a correct Laurent series expansion *outside* that disk.

The first one is valid in the disk, and it shows (although circuitously) that the residue at $0$ is $0$, because the function is in fact holomorphic there. This was really already visible from the algebraic expression.

The second expansion is only valid *outside* that disk centered at $0$, so does not give info in a straightforward way about what happens *inside*...

Comment: I can believe this is true. Is there any reason why dividing in these two ways yields this distinction?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that $res(z_{0},f)=\lim_{z \to z_{0}} (z-z_{0})f(z)$ once $f(0)=\frac{1}{4}$$-f$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $0$ and so $res(0,\frac{2}{z^2-4z+8})=0$. If you prefer you can also notice that $f$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$ then through its Taylor series $res(0,\frac{2}{z^2-4z+8})=0$.